# Word length frequency in C Program

Tags: c, string, loops

I am trying to write a simple C program to output the length of words and output their frequencies. For example, if the user inputs "hey" my program would output Length of word: 3 Occurrences 1, and so on with a larger string inputted. I just cannot seem to loop it properly. I thought of setting both counters when a delimiter is seen to count both the length of the word at the time and its occurrence but I have not found a way for it to work. How can I fix my loop? My code is below. I'd appreciate any help. I should include my program only runs correctly for one word inputted but not a whole sentence or multiple sentences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
const char delim[] = ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"";
const int n_delim = 31;
#define SIZE 1000

int is_delim(int c);
int main(){
    char string[SIZE];
    int wordlength = 0, wl[SIZE];
    int word = 0, i;


    printf("Enter your input string:");
    fgets(string, SIZE, stdin);
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';

printf("Word Length\tCount\n");
    int seen = 0;
    int l;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
        if (is_delim(string[i])){
            wl[word++] = wordlength;
            l = wordlength;
            seen++;
            printf("%d\t\t%d\n", l, seen);
            wordlength = 0;
        }
        wordlength++;

    }
    return 0;
}

int is_delim(int c){
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_delim; i++)
        if (c == delim[i]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, you never declare `i` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my error will fix it right now.

Comment: Also you never use `wl` anywhere, if you compile with `Wall` you will see these things.

Comment: Isn't wl used with wl[word++] @Linus?

Comment: @Benny You left space in `delim` intentionally ? If not the while comparing it will also be compared .

Comment: You define wl, but you never *use* it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Linus yes to allow users to enter multiple sentences using spaces after or before punctuation marks

Comment: @Benny Do you need to keep track of the number of times a word of x length is seen. (e.g. like 3-letter words seen 8 times, 4-letter words seen 4 times, etc.)? So you don't need to count the number of `Hey`s you see, just `3`'s?

Comment: Yes I would like that @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: There is a simple solution. Declare an array `int occurs[64] = {0};` (initialized to zero) and long enough to so the last index is higher than the longest word is long. Then every time you compute a string length, just increment your array at that length (e.g. `occurs[length]++;`. When you are done, all your occurrences for each length are stored in the array for you. (e.g. if you had 7 words of length 3, then `occur[3] = 7` (and so on throughout the array). Just `for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) printf ("occur[%2d] : %d\n", i, occur[i]);` to print them all. Eliminates lots of work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that wl[n] holds the count of words
of length n. Also, you don't need to keep calling strlen()
on every iteration, just check for the zero byte at the end.
The optimizer will do this for you, if you enable it.
The odd-looking for(;1;) is so that the loop counts
the final word, which is terminated by the zero byte.

```
memset(wl,0,sizeof(wl));
for(wordStart=maxLength=i=0;1;i++) {
  if(is_delim(string[i]) || string[i]==0) {
    int wordLength= i-wordStart;
    if(wordLength>0)
      wl[wordLength]++;
    if(wordLength>maxLength)
      maxLength= wordLength;
    wordStart= i+1;
  }
  if(string[i]==0)
    break;
}

for(i=1;i<=maxLength;i++) {
  if(wl[i]>0) {
    printf("%d words of length %d.\n",wl[i],i);
  }
}
```

Comment: is memset in a certain library I do not have included? Because I compiled the program by also replacing my loop with this code by nothing was outputted? I set both wordStart and maxLength to int as that was not included here.@TeasingDart

Comment: There was a misplaced parethesis in the if(is_delim...) statement. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yes it compiled perfectly now @TeasingDart. Thank you for the help as well!

Comment: A couple last notes: C strings are terminated by a zero byte, so if you are iterating through each character you can just check for zero and avoid calling strlen(). Your is_delim() should also return true if the character is zero. The n_delim variable is redundant and should be removed. Don't use the "register" attribute, let the compiler decide how to use the registers.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use `strtok` for this. Right now, you never compare the last string with the current one so you can't tell them apart. You can use `strcmp` for this. Finally instead of manually testing the length of the string you should use `strlen`. Here is how your loop could look like

```
int seen = 0;

pch = strtok(string, delim);
last = pch;
while(pch != NULL) {
  if(strcmp(last, pch) != 0) {
    printf("%s:\t%d\t\t%d\n", last, (int)strlen(last), seen);
    seen = 1;
  }else {
    seen++;
  }
  last = pch;
  pch = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
printf("%s:\t%d\t\t%d\n", last, (int)strlen(last), seen);
```

Note, you should set the variable `seen` to 0 before the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @Linus. I replaced my loop with this loop on my compiler and it works except for the first word inputted. It displays its length but count outputs garbage why could that be?

Comment: wl[] is allocated on the stack and will contain stack garbage, you need to clear it using memset(wl,0,sizeof(wl))

Comment: I realized what was outputting the garbage. The first seen declared has no value assigned to it.

Comment: @Benny That would be why I'll edit my answer to clearify that.